# Format an excel column to "yyyy-MM-dd" via .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, excel

I'm trying to format an excel column that I created in a .net application. I send the excel sheet the correct formatted date, however, Excel for some reason seems to be formatting it in a way of its own. The following is what I have, but it doesn't work:

```
sheet.Cells[i, 2] = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(dr["date"].ToString())); //yyyy-mm-dd
                    ((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 2]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

The format I'm getting is mm/dd/yyyy. How can I format this column? Thank you in advance.

**Added**
Don't know if this matters but this is how I'm saving the excel file:

```
 wb.SaveAs(FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV,
                          null, null, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                          false, false, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 2]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
sheet.Cells[i, 2].Value2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["date"].ToString());
```

or simply (using strings)

```
((Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 2]).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
sheet.Cells[i, 2].Value2 = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["date"].ToString())
                           .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

Comment: There's no error at all. The issue is that when I open the Excel file it's still in mm/dd/yyyy format.

Comment: @Eric: did you save your excel file after applying that code?

Comment: Yes, I did using  wb.SaveAs(FileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV, 
                          null, null, false, false, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, 
                          false, false, null, null, null);

Comment: @Eric: you're saving your file as CSV: that format doesn't support _formatting_. Try to save as Excel file and see if it used correctly when reopening.. Anyway, take a look at my edited post...

Comment: The file has to be in a CSV format as it will be uploaded to a portal that will only receive CSV files.

Comment: @Eric: the idea is to _store_ date value as a string, telling Excel to think it as a string (see different NumberFormat)

Comment: It's almost correct except that the month is showing up as 00. I tried capitalizing the 'mm' but to no avail.

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it changes it to MM/dd/yyyy in excel. If i don't capitalize the MM's then the date looks fine EXcept for the month which appears as two 0's

Comment: @Eric: no, the format I gave you is correct and you should use that. Do not reopen CSV file with Excel because Excel will format it as it wants; use Notepad or whatever text editor indeed...

Answer (score 1):

Don't open it in Excel, Excel will reformat any CSV file it opens and show dates and times using your system regional settings.

Instead, look at your CSV file in a normal text editor, such as notepad.